# Are there any ways to get value of a table in a form but the table column was made with "document.getElementByID(id)"?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm just wondering if there are any ways to get the value of the `document.getElementById(id)` through forms using `$_POST[]` of `php`? Below is an example to which I'm trying to figure out how I could make it work. How the code below works is that when I click a table cell it will copy whatever the cell have and add it to my cart table and I would want to associate this cart table to a form where I could send it to my php script and get the data in the table but this cart table is produced by javascript just to be clear. Anyways here is the code below:

```
   <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM userItems WHERE item_category = $choice" ;                
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($row as $item):
            echo '<tbody style="width:100%;height:100%;">';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo      '  <td  id="'.$item['item_name'].'" onclick="copyItem(id)" style="margin:-1px;width:261px;"> '.$item['item_name'] .'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</tbody>';

        endforeach;
   ?>

<script>
function copyItem(id) 
{
    var table = document.getElementById("cart");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var value = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;

    var values = document.createElement("input").type="text".name="items[]".value=values;
    // var sent = '<span><input type="text" name="items[]" value="" size="15" /></span>\r\n';
    var dummy = '<span><input type="text" name="unitprice[]" size="30"/></span>\r\n';
    var dummy1 = '<span><input type="number" name="qty[]" size="15"/></span>\r\n';
    var dummy2  = '<span><input type="text" name="totalamount[]" size="15"/></span>\r\n';
    var dummy3 = '<span><button class="btn btn-danger active" type="button" style="height:25px;width:68px;padding:2px;" onclick = "deleteRow(this)" >Delete </button></span>\r\n';
    cell1.innerHTML = values;
    cell2.innerHTML = dummy;
    cell3.innerHTML = dummy1;
    cell4.innerHTML = dummy2;
    cell5.innerHTML = dummy3;
}

</script>
```

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you write the php variable in the js function:

```
 <?php 
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM userItems WHERE item_category = $choice" ;                
         $result = $db->query($sql);
         $row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         foreach($row as $item):
                    echo '<tbody style="width:100%;height:100%;">';
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo      '  <td  id="'.$item['item_name'].'" onclick="copyItem('.$item['item_name'].')" style="margin:-1px;width:261px;"> '.$item['item_name'] .'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    echo '</tbody>';

                 endforeach;
   ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment but even so my script will already take the $item['item_name'] value because it will point to the id of <td tag> and also I've updated my question because I think we are misunderstanding, but anyways, I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand.. i can sayd to you that if you want to send a document.getElementById(id) on a $_POST[] you must to send a form submit via ajax call and send it in the data property.